# Configure an ASP.NET MVC3 project using Membership Provider to work with SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, sql-server-ce

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project that I just created using the project template that includes the Membership provider all set up in a default manner.  I'm now trying to configure the the project to utilize SQL Server CE as a data source.  I'm following this blog article without much success.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

Half way down the article you'll find the subheading "Walkthrough 2: Using EF Code-First with SQL CE and ASP.NET MVC 3", which is the portion that I am trying to follow.

According to my understanding, all I should need to do is to configure my connection string in the web.config file so that it will utilize SQL Server CE.  And as soon as I run the application and try to create a new user, the CE database file should automatically be created in my App_Data directory and I should be up and running.  Granted this walkthrough is doing things a bit differently and is not using Membership Provider, but I should be pulling the underlying concepts from this and still having success.  Instead I am getting an error when I try to create a new user saying that it could not find the data source.

I'm using the following for my connection string in the web.config file...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|AppData.sdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard membership provider only supports SQL Server, but you can use the new Universal Provider available via NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers